# Existence and uniqueness for matrix ODE $X' = f(X) A X$, with $f$ linear

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, initial-value-problems

This is probably a rather trivial question, but nevertheless I think I need help.

I am interested in studying the following initial value problem in $X \colon (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
X' = f(X) A X\\
X(0)=x
\end{cases}
\,.
\end{equation}
Here $f$ is a given *linear* function $\mathbb{R}^{m} \to \mathbb{R}$, whereas $A$ a given matrix function $I \to \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$.

My question is: Does the solution of this problem exist for any arbitrary choice of functions $f$, $A$, and interval $(a,b)$?

I know that, if $f \equiv 1$, then we have indeed existence and uniqueness.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.science.unitn.it/~bagagiol/noteODE.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwistcmQ1rrqAhXi_CoKHSgoCXUQFjAQegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw3TPv-i3DJU2ihMsgeHcZei&cshid=1594108886574 check p19 for existence thms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you inherit all claims of the standard existence and uniqueness theorems for local solutions.

No if you want the existence of a solution over the fixed interval $I$. The standard non-linear counter-example applies, $y'=y^2$ has the given form with $f(y)=y$ and $A=1$. Depending on the initial value, the solution can blow up inside the interval.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your counter-example applies in the special case where $m=1$, right? What if we assumed $m>1$?

Comment: Then you could still easily construct examples where this equation is the first component. What you can do is restrict the initial values to some small set so that there is a larger set that the solution remains inside for all of the interval.